# Can I see the connection string in DBeaver and copy it to make a connection to DB2 in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, db2, dbeaver

I try to connect to a DB2 database in Python. I have already a running connection to that database in DBeaver, so I is it possible to get the connection string from DBeaver to connect to the database in Python?
I'm asking since my other approches to get a running connection from Python did not work.

Comment: DBeaver uses JDBC.  Python uses CLI (odbc).  Different drivers. But the connection strings can be mostly identical. However, your question is bad because it says "python did not work". That is NOT an error description. BE SPECIFIC.  Edit your questions to give exact details of versions, what you installed, what your environment/platform is etc.

Comment: @mao Thanks for your help! see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548538/how-to-connect-python-to-a-db2-database-with-ssl?noredirect=1#comment107118866_60548538